# ANT SSHEXEC failing with Algorithm negotitation fail error

Tags: ant, ssh, jsch

I am just trying to connect to a remote host using the ant sshexec task . I have the required jar in the ant lib directory and able to connect to the remote host using putty.
This is the way i am running the ssh

```
 <sshexec host="host"
username="username"
password="password"
trust="yes"
command="ls"/>
```

There seems to be encryption algorith mismatch with the server. How can i specify the algorith as I don't see any attribute for this task [Ant doc][1]. This is the error log i am getting:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:540)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:288)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:145)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHBase.openSession(SSHBase.java:212)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec.execute(SSHExec.java:158)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[jsch]+Algorithm+negotiation+fail

Comment: @MarkO'Connor That's being handled through java program which potentially has an option to set the algorithm option. How to i set these through ant ?

Comment: Looks like the fix is applied either on the server (enable the algorithms being used by your version of JSCH) or alter the policy files used by your JVM. I have never experienced this issue, but doesn't look like an ANT specific issue.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Thanks for the reply. I know that it's server specific and I have too little idea on jsch . Can me point me to the location where i can find which algorithm has been used by a version of jsch and how can i enable the algorithms on the server and so on

Comment: I stand corrected. Googling suggests that there is a programmatic fix available See: https://www.mail-archive.com/jsch-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01633.html . I would suggest raising an Apache ANT bug, reporting this problem.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR edit your sshd_config and enable support for diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 and diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 in KexAlgorithms:

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
I suspect that the problem appeared after the following change in OpenSSH 6.7: "The default set of ciphers and MACs has been altered to remove unsafe algorithms.". (see [changelog](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.7)). This version was released on Oct, 6, and made it on Oct, 21 to Debian testing (see [Debian changelog](https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/openssh/+changelog)).

OpenSSH enables only the following key exchange algorithms by default:

curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
ecdh-sha2-nistp256
ecdh-sha2-nistp384
ecdh-sha2-nistp521
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
Whereas JSch claims to support [these algorithms](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) (see under "features") for key exchange:

diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
So indeed, they cannot agree on a common key exchange algorithm. Updating sshd_config (and restarting the SSH server) does the trick. Apparently JSch is supposed to support the "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256" method since version 0.1.50 (see [changelog](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ChangeLog)).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error trying to connect to OS X 10.11.6 and could fix it by replacing `~/.ant/lib/jsch-0.1.51.jar` with the latest `~/.ant/lib/jsch-0.1.54.jar`.